# Create a People Search Result Source Using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, powershell, result-source

I want to set Type="People Search Results" and in Credential Information want to set default authentication using PowerShell. I have used below code to create result source but I am not able to set Type and credential information property using PowerShell.

```
# create manager instances
$fedManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Query.FederationManager($sspApp)
$searchOwner =  Get-SPEnterpriseSearchOwner -Level Ssa 

# define query

$queryProperties = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.QueryTransformProperties

# define custom sorting
$sortCollection = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortCollection
$sortCollection.Add("Title", [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortDirection]::Ascending)
$queryProperties["SortList"] = [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortCollection]$sortCollection

# create result source
$resultSource = $fedManager.GetSourceByName($name,$searchOwner)
Write-Host $resultSources.ResultSource.ToString()
Write-Host $resultSource
if($resultSource)
{
        Write-Host "Result Source : $name already exist. Deleting..."
        $fedManager.RemoveSource($resultSource)
}
Write-Host "Result Source : $name Creating..."
$resultSource = $fedManager.CreateSource($searchOwner)
$resultSource.Name = $name

$resultSource.ProviderId = $fedManager.ListProviders()[$protocol].Id
$resultSource.CreateQueryTransform($queryProperties, $queryTransform)
$resultSource.Commit()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- To set the Type property to People Results, you need to update the
  Source.ProviderId to equal [SearchProvider](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.query.searchprovider).LocalPeopleProviderGuid;
- To set Default Authentication, you need to update the [Source](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.query.source).[AuthInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.query.source.authinfo) to equal a new [AuthenticationInformation](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.authenticationinformation)([FederationAuthType](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.federationauthtype).LocalNTAuth) object;
- If you need other credentials, then create a new object of type [AccountAuthCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.accountauthcredentials) and set it as the Data property of Source.AuthInfo.

Answer (score 1):

If you would want to set `Type="People Search Results"`, then I recommend you update your code with below. I have created this way.

```
$resultSource.ProviderId = $fedManager.ListProviders()['Local People Provider'].Id
```